# Buffering and file I/O in C

Tags: c, delphi, file-io

Many years ago I noticed when reading a large binary file by `BlockRead()` in Delphi 7 that the speed is much lower when the file is being read byte by byte compared to when each time a chunk of, say, 16384 bytes, is read. It obviously meant that Delphi 7 didn't use an internal buffer (at least, by default) and each time the `BlockRead()` directly read from the disc.

What about `fread()` in C? Should the developer manage buffering herself/himself or the C library will take care of it? I know that text file I/O is buffered by default in C and, as far as I can remember, it is possible to change the size of the internal buffer.

UPDATE: I think that it is possible that Delphi 7 did use an internal buffer for an opened file but its default size was small.

Comment: There are so many levels of buffering: disk device driver buffers, file system cache, library/fread buffers and now your program buffers... Your program knows best which blocks are required frequently; the cache counts hits and flushes unused blocks and will approach your program's knowledge with heuristics.. Maybe just don't worry about it.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it, as you did with Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

According to the book *C: In a Nutshell* (2005) by T. Crawford and P. Prinz

> When you open an ordinary file by calling `fopen( )`, the new stream is fully buffered. ... After you have opened a file, and before you perform the first input or output operation on it, you can change the buffering mode using the `setbuf( )` or `setvbuf( )` function.

It seems that this is about files in general, not only text files.

I will update this answer soon with the result of some tests.